# Subquery and Indexing for IP Information

Tags: mysql, geoip

I'm having a problem trying to cross-reference between a table with user information and a table with geolocation data (from GeoIP's database).

I have the IP address in standard format (not integer) in the user table, and the GeoIP data in the GeoIP table, with the integer IP ranges.

This query works, but is very slow and unoptimized.

```
SELECT email, country 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN geoip ON users.ip BETWEEN geoip.startip AND geoip.endip
```

I feel like I'm missing something very easy here.

UPDATE: This query works, but is very slow - is there any way to index it to make it go faster?  Right now, no matter when run, each row would take about 300-500ms to execute, which is way too slow.

```
SELECT email, country 
FROM users INNER JOIN geoip ON INET_ATON(users.ip) 
BETWEEN geoip.startip AND geoip.endip
```

Thanks!

UPDATE 2: Here's the EXPLAIN output on the query:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geoip     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  3651972 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 87996123 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

I can't add an integer-only IP row right now because the DB's in use and it's over 90 million rows; it'll be something I look into doing during some downtime, but right now, I'd like to get it running this way.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment yet, so here's an 'answer' ...

Are you sure it works? If I understand your description correctly, you have users.ip as CIDR notation in char or varchar and geoip.startip/endip as integer. As such, this query has no way to compare these two correctly.

Correct way of doing this would be either

```
SELECT email, country 
FROM users INNER JOIN geoip ON INET_ATON(users.ip) 
BETWEEN geoip.startip AND geoip.endip
```

or

```
SELECT email, country 
FROM users INNER JOIN geoip ON users.ip 
BETWEEN INET_NTOA(geoip.startip) AND INET_NTOA(geoip.endip)
```

which is the better one pretty much depending on which table is larger (more rows).

The best way to do this, though, would be to store users.ip as integer (or another column with integer interpretation).

Comment: The first query works, but is very slow - is there any way to index this to make it run faster?  Right now, no matter what, it takes at least 300-500ms per row.

Comment: Do you have indexes on geoip.startip and geoip.endip?

Comment: Yes, and also an index on startip, endip and country together.

Comment: Unless you use it in WHERE, SORT, JOIN or such clauses, you don't need an index on country ... Can you provide what `DESCRIBE your_query` says? Also, can you try adding integer ip to your users table and try joining using that column instead of CIDR ip? (`ALTER TABLE users ADD (intip int usigned), ADD INDEX intip(intip); UPDATE users SET intip = INET_ATON(ip);`)

Comment: I've added the EXPLAIN output to the question.  Right now, I can't add the IP row in question but hope to do so during some downtime (the DB is in use and is 90 million rows).

Comment: well if what you say is correct, then the query would take about half a day. and it seems you succesfuly run it several times in las day :) So i suspect you either use some kind of where, or limit clause in your query. is that correct? do you modify the query in any other way?